# extension that creates StackOverflow exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I wrote a function extension to a class. This extenssion function returns IList as result.
Most of the times I would like to convert the IList to an array T[].
This is requires me to declare "using System.Linq;" in every class that converts IList to T[].
So in order to save for me the declaration of "using System.Linq;" I wrote an extension in the same class of my original extenssion (so I wouldn't have to declare "using"):

```
    public static T[] ToArray<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

Of course that the extenssion class have "using System.Linq;", but this is the only place I need to put this declaration.
The problem is that I get StackOverflow exception since the command "list.ToArray();" actually calls recoursivly to itself and not to the original ToArray.
I can change the name of the function - MakeArray instead of ToArray but I would like to keep my naming conventions.
Maybe do you have any solutions?

Comment: Seriously? You're going through all of this extra work to save yourself from adding `using System.Linq;` to the top of a few source files? That's just *nuts*. Your problems will go away if you do things the right way, instead of with some absurd hack. In the time it took you to write this question, you could have copied and pasted the `using` declaration into *all* of your source files.

Comment: But surely now you need to add reference and a using clause to "My.Static.Extensions" - isn't this a zero sum game?

Comment: @nonnb: I guess the point is that all the rest of his source is in the same namespace. But yes, it's a very silly position to take, IMO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, I'd strongly advise you *not* to do this. You've "saved" one line (a single using directive) and added four lines which don't work. Why is a single using directive so painful to you? It's out of the way of the rest of the code, and is almost entirely innocuous... as well as providing you all the *other* benefits of LINQ, of course.

If you really *must* do this, you could just call the LINQ version explicitly:

```
public static T[] ToArray<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    return System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(list);
}
```

But *just don't*.

Comment: I have more then 100 files and not "few" source files.

Comment: @Naor: If you've got a hundred classes in the same namespace, you should at least be considering whether that's really a good idea. But even so, it's a single line in each file - why do you consider that a problem?

Comment: @Naor: even if your IDE doesn't provide any ways to add usings easily, you are a programmer, dammit. Fire up your scripting language of choice and put the line in all the files you need, whether it's 100 or 100000.

Comment: @Naor: Even if you do have 100 source files, do you really need to change some IList<T> to a T[] in _every_ one of those files, surely you don't explicitly require an array instead of an IEnumerable or IList etc in all your files, I would have thought you could limit this to just a few special cases where an array is genuinely required?